# Wordpress Add Custom data tables in User Profile - Not Custom Field

Tags: wordpress, custom-data-type

I am kind a new to wordpress and need guidance. But understand PHP.
I need to add custom tables with data ( Repeater fields is optional/ HTML field ) in User's profile. User Cannot edit those data ( read only )

Data will be manually added from Admin Dashboard > Users. I assume there should be a field in there for admin to add those data

Then, User can read it from their profile page / Data presented in user's profile.

Those data will be something like a set of 3 tabs with Transaction list and history.So each user has different data.

I had searched but all only show tutorials on adding custom Field in User Registration.

Assistance please. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Advanced custom fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com) for this. What you do is that you add a field to users add/edit page with ACF. If you have frontend user profile page. You can get the data from this fields with the function `get_field('my_custom_field', $userID)`

If you don't have and frontend user profile page, and will let your users go thru the "backend" profile page you will need to add som functions that disables so an user can't edit those fields if you don't want the users to edit them. You can do that with the filter `add_filter('acf/load_field', 'my_filter);`

The rest how you do this should you be able to find on ACF documentation page.

Comment: Hi Thanks...for the help.

Actually, the data/ info will be added by the Administrator only. User will only read/ see whatever data is added by the admin. User cannot edit the info. the info will be presented just like ordinary post to users. and Each users has different information entry.

Is this possible ?